# GLEW and openGL deprecation

Tags: c++, opengl, deprecated, glew

I am using openGL and glew to check the extensions.

Say I wanted to check if I could use multitexture extension:

GLEW_ARB_multitexture   will return true if I can use it.

BUT

arb_multitexture was deprecated in openGL 3.0.

Will it still return true?

What about in 3.1 where it was removed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'll return true if your context exports the extension, which it will if it's not "forward-compatible" or "core profile", or possibly if it supports the "GL_ARB_compatibility" extension.

The bottom line is, if GLEW_ARB_multitexture is true, you can use the functionality.  Any higher-level logic (like only using shaders if they're available) is up to you.